# Attach_file() cannot find input's id

Tags: selenium, capybara

I am testing with Capybara and Selenium.
This is my inspection:

```
<form id="fileuploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false;" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="NFI-wrapper nice" id="NFI-wrapper-14302252427892468" style="overflow: auto; display: inline-block;">
    <div class="NFI-button NFI14302252427892468" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: block; float: left; white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;">
      Browse...
      <input type="file" id="attachmentfiles" class="nice NFI-current" multiple="" data-styled="true" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; cursor: pointer; height: 60px;">
    </div>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="NFI-filename NFI14302252427892468" style="display: block; float: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 5px;">
  </div>
</form>
```

If I try to attach_file("attachmentfiles", "some_path"), I get an error saying:

```
Unable to find file field "attachmentfiles"
```

If I search the same input through all("input")[0] I get the following:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field #<Capybara::Element tag="input">
```

The tag 'form' behaves the same way.
I really don't understand what should I do in this case to upload a file.

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can do is defining:

`Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false`

Another is, just add `visible: false` as 3rd parameter to attach_file()